# @RouteResource does not work

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I'm using `FosRestBundle` and I'm declaring a controller with manually routes.

```
namespace Cboujon\PropertyBundle\Controller;

use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\QueryParam;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\Get;


/**
 * Property controller.
 * @RouteResource("Property")
 */
class PropertyRESTController extends \FOS\RestBundle\Controller\FOSRestController {


    /**
     * 
     * @return type
     * @Get("/types")
     * 
     */
    public function getTypesAction() {
        ...
        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle($view);
    }

}
```

**routing.yml**

```
cboujon_property_property_api:
    resource: "@CboujonPropertyBundle/Controller/PropertyRESTController.php"
    type:     rest
    prefix:   /api
```

When I do the request `http://localhost:8000/api/properties/types` or `http://localhost:8000/api/property/types` I get

> 404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException.

But if `http://localhost:8000/api/types` it works!

I need to config the url `http://localhost:8000/api/properties/types`. What am I doing wrong?

**Update 1**

There is no Property entity. PropertyController should do custom operations (No CRUD).

**Update 2**

You can see the [git repository](https://github.com/Overflow012/property/tree/master/)

Comment: The `RouteResource` looks like it's just to change the name (eg, `FooController` using the resource `Property` rather than `Foo`). It looks like your routing.yml should have `parent: property` in the definition for the `types` routes.

Comment: @Qoop, sorry but I don't understand, why my routing.yml should have `parent: property`? My other controllers defined does not need it and I didn't have any error with them.

Comment: you dont need `RouteResource` annotation when you will define custom routes for all Controller actions and if you will define prefix for all actions, can use `@Prefix` anotation on class controller

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You simply cannot mix implicit and explicit route generation (for a single route) in FOSRestBundle.

`@RouteResource` is meant for "prefixing" during implicit route generation, while `@Get` is meant for explicit routing.

Also, implicit routing is meant to speedup standard CRUD resource editing, so it is **NOT** your case: just go for the explicit routing and avoid all the complication. You can still benefit of other FOSRestBundle features, like View handler, `@ParamFetcher`s, ...

### Why

With implicit route generation, the route is extracted from the method name (e.g. `postTypeAction` becomes something like `POST /type`,
`cgetTypeAction` becomes something like `GET /types`).

If you choose the explicit way, you use `@Route`, `@Get`, `@Post`, ... annotations, to set the resource URL to whatever you want. With explicit routing,
`@RouteResource` doesn't make sense; just use the standard Symfony prefixes.

The annotation `@RouteResource` on the other hand, is there so that you can customize the [route resource name](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#implicit-resource-name-definition) (e.g. get_RESOURCE_myaction).

### Debug you code

To clarify, here some output of `app/console debug:router` from your code (I've applied some syntax fix to your project to run this commands).

**NOTE**: I've set the prefix to `/api/prefix` to avoid confusions

`@RouteResource` + `@Get` (This explain why you get 404 errors):

```
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path                              
 get_property_types       GET    ANY    ANY  /api/prefix/types.{_format}
```

`@RouteResource` only (note that implicit naming take place):

```
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path                              
 get_property_types       GET    ANY    ANY  /api/prefix/property/types.{_format}
```

`@Get` only (note it is the same of your current scenario, just the route name changes since is not set in `@Get`):

```
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path                              
 get_types                GET    ANY    ANY  /api/prefix/types.{_format}
```

Removing both (is still the same, but.. just a coincidence since your method is called `getTypesAction`):

```
 Name                     Method Scheme Host Path                              
 get_types                GET    ANY    ANY  /api/prefix/types.{_format}
```

### An Off-Topic Note

In OOP, a `static abstract function` cannot be defined. A `static` method is defined at class level, so no polymorphism can take place because PHP
cannot know in advance which sub-class is to be used. When the method is NOT static, PHP knows the object class (since can access `$this`) and you
can have polymorphic behaviour.

In your class `Cboujon\PropertyBundle\Entity\Property` you need to remove the method `static abstract function getLabel` or define it
as `abstract function getLabel`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you should change prefix in routing.yml from

```
perifx: /api
```

to

```
prefix: /api/properties
```

to have this url `http://localhost:8000/api/properties/types`

Comment: Michal, I should be able to set the `properties` part in controller as annotation, not as prefix.

Comment: Another solution could be `@Get("/properties/types")` but it's ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can simply remove the `@GET` annotation from your `getTypesAction()` method and rely on the default route creation behaviour of FOSRestBundle (your method will then be accessible via `/api/property/types`).

Edit: Basically, this is what is described on http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/5-automatic-route-generation_single-restful-controller.html#define-resource-actions.

Comment: I have been tried remove `@GET` but I still get 404 error.

Comment: Please, see my **Update 2**

Comment: Can you please post the output of `php app/console debug:router` after removing the `@GET` annotation?